# Access a class with the array operator in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have a bunch of classes for MovieClips in my library, such as

```
ship_3000aa
ship_3000ab
ship_3001aa
```

and so on.

I need to access them like this:

```
var image_key:String = "3000aa";
var ship:MovieClip = new _root["ship_"+image_key]();
```

All of this is happens inside a class, and all MovieClips are exported to frame 2, which is where the class in which this happens is instantiated.

*root is the base root.  "root" without "*" is not found. The property is null on _root.  The property does not exists on _stage either.

Is there a correct way to instantiate a library MovieClip class using the array access operator from within a class?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you can instantiate an object by keeping the classes in an Array:

```
var classArray:Array = [ship_3000aa, ship_3000ab, ship_3001aa];
var ship:MovieClip = new classArray[2]();
```

or instantiate an object by the class name by using `flash.utils.getDefinitionByName` (probably more useful in your case):

```
var imageKey:String = "3000aa";
var ShipClass:Class = getDefinitionByName("ship_" + imageKey) as Class;
var ship:MovieClip = new ShipClass();
```